# in Python google colab

Tags: python

in python x is not defined  please solve my problem

when using scaling in python x is not defined my coding is as follows
from sklearn.preprocessing import scale

---

NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 x_scaled=pd.DataFrame(scale(x), columns=x.columns)

NameError: name 'x' is not defined

please solve this

Comment: We can't give you any help without seeing the actual code, but the key problem is that `x.columns` being passed to the `columns` keyword parameter is invalid because `x` is not defined in the scope of the call to `pd.DataFrame()`

Answer (score 0):

#### You have not defined a value for `x`

Note that your question is mistyped. You *say* that "X is not defined", but the *error message* is that `x` is not defined.

Remember that in Python, `X` and `x` are different things.

Check that you have not been creating an `X` and then trying to access `x`.